# All or nothing - fast heuristic shortest path algorithm (parallel?)

Tags: c, algorithm, cuda, parallel-processing, shortest-path

I'm looking for a good way to find a shortest path between two points in a network (directed, cyclic, weighted) of billions of nodes. Basically I want an algorithm that will typically get a solution very very quickly, even if its worst case is horrible.

I'm open to parallel or distributed algorithms, although it would have to make sense with the size of the data set (an algorithm that would work with CUDA on a graphics card would have to be able to be processed in chunks). I don't plan on using a farm of computers to do this, but potentially a few max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A google search gives you a lot of good [links](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=parallel%20dijkstra%20algorithm). The first [link](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node35.html) itself talks about parallel implementations of two shortest path algorithms.

And talking about implementation on CUDA, you will have to remember that billions of nodes =  Gigabytes of memory. That would provide a limitation on the nodes you can use per card (for optimum performance) at a time. The maximum capacity of a [graphics card](http://www.nvidia.com/object/personal-supercomputing.html) currently in the market is about 6GB. This can give you an estimate on the number of cards you may need to use (not necessarily the number of machines).

Answer (score 1):

Look at Dikstra's algorithm.  Generally it does an optimized multi-depth breadth first search until you're guaranteed to have found the shortest path.  The first path found might be the shortest, but you can't be sure until the other branches of the search don't terminate with a shorter distance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an uniform cost search. This search algorithm will find a optimal solution in a weighted graph. If I remember correctly, the search complexity (space and time) is b^(C*/e+1), where b denotes the branching, C* the optimal path cost to your goal, and e is the average path cost.

And there is also something called bidirectional search, where you start from the initial state and goal state with the search and hopefully both starting points crosses each other somewhere in the middle of the graph :)

Answer (score 0):

I am worried that unless your graph is somehow nicely layed out in the memory, you won't get much benefit from using CUDA, when compared to a well-tuned parallel algorithm on CPU. The problem is, that walking on a "totally-unordered" graphs lead to a lot of random memory accesses.

When you have 32 CUDA-threads working together in parallel, but their memory access is random, the fetch instruction has to be serialised. Since the search algorithm does not perform many hard mathematical computations, fetching memory is where you are likely to loose most of your time.